# I deleted two activities in android studio and got this error, is there a solution?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I deleted two activities in android studio and got this error, is there a solution?

```
Android resource linking failed
com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-29:/layout-w936dp-v13/content_scrolling.xml:22: error: resource string/large_text (aka com.example.myapplication:string/large_text) not found.
com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-29:/layout-w936dp-v13/viewholder2.xml:24: error: resource drawable/m__1_ (aka com.example.myapplication:drawable/m__1_) not found.
com.example.myapplication.app-mergeDebugResources-29:/layout-w1240dp-v13/content_scrolling.xml:17: error: resource string/large_text (aka com.example.myapplication:string/large_text) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

I tried to return them but I couldn't.

Comment: search in your project where they are used, and delete those lines

Comment: I did it, but it was not used anywhere

Comment: if they're not used, the system won't try to find them, and you won't get errors like this.

Comment: Does this mean it could be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Comment: Please add more detail to this answer. Showing your working and providing details can help others who are experiencing similar issues.